# Jenkins Roles access with github authentication does not work

Tags: jenkins

I have created jenkins with github authentication ( Securtiy realm)  working as expected , when Authorization used as Role-Based Strategy, it does not work. simply it will take credentials and always shows Jenkins home page

any help appreciated

Comment: Just to be on the same page , have you created groups like admin , others and assigned them required privileges ?

Comment: yes i have created roles and assigned them , after assigning the roles , it is unable to login to the jenkins

Comment: what  security realm you are using in jenkins ?

Comment: github authentication i was using , i think there is some issue with 1.659 jenkins version , I tired with 2.0 version it worked for me seamlessly

Comment: 1.659.1.1 version worked fine , as per jira logs 1.659.1.2 onwards , it has security issue . also has some workaround for it

Comment: Jenkins 2.277.4 - I have the same problem with Jenkins API. Role Based Authorization strategy just does not work with Gitlab Authentication Plugin (Error: <user> is missing the Overall/Read permission).